# TextBox event for only user input

Tags: c#, events, textbox

I have a Textbox control which sometimes updated programmatically and also can be update by the user.
How can I distinct between those two event?
I'd like to have a "Dirty" flag set to "True" when the user changes the text.

Comment: Are you [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)?

Comment: no data binding for this control...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Key Down event of the text box.

```
  private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      // Insert the code you want to run when the text changes here!
  }
```

Comment: this event is valid for textbox but i wonder what about other controls like NumericUpDown...

Comment: Yeah, this solution isn't the cleanest for all controls.  However, the numericupdown control does have both the keydown event and the mousedown event.  I suppose you could use both of them along with tracking of the value of the control.  Alternatively, you could always just throw a boolean flag every time you programatically change the value, then check the boolean flag in the ValueChanged event for the control (setting it back to the default before continuing your processing).  That's certainly a very simple solution - maybe not the most elegant though.

Comment: This doesn't work if the user cuts and pastes data in the textbox with the mouse.

Comment: Yeah - you'd probably have to go with MouseDown as well.

Comment: It might be worth to note that this only detects character input. Removing data from the control with the DEL key for example, isn't being caught by this. A workaround would be using KeyUp and KeyDown events but this still looks a poor solution to me.

Comment: @Vinzenz That is simply not true.  Just caught the delete key (key value 46) using this code.

Answer (score 15):

Check Modified property of TextBox on the TextChanged event. If true, the changes were made by user, otherwise the text was changed programmatically.

Example:

```
void Texbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Modified)
        TextboxUserInput();
}
```

Comment: I would just say thank you for this one. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

my solution
work for type , copy and paste

```
    private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).ContainsFocus)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What if the control has focus, but the text is being changed programatically?

Comment: use Textchnaged delegate for union of controls and use else for programatically change

Answer (score 4):

avoid setting the "dirty" flag when done programmatically. Disable the event handler or set a flag that says "this is code, not the user"

Comment: Disabling the event handler for the duration of the inline changes is a great idea. It also solves any problems you might have by users pasting text into the box.

Answer (score 0):

try onBlur

this will catch the moment the user leaves the field.

You can work it up in conjunction with onFocus to save the value before editing

Comment: good idea but not 100% effective. Would be a bit "cleaner" than my answer

Comment: "Cleanliness" is meaningless if it doesn't work.  Simply detaching the handler is pretty standard for this sort of thing.

Comment: He's not talking about the disabled handler, but about the extra flag. Well, it's ither an extra flag or an extra handler...