# Checking if a TextChanged event in C# was triggered by the code or by the user

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a new application and I need to edit a TextBox with code at runtime. However, there is a TextChanged event handler which is triggered when the code edits the box. How can i detect if the box has been edited by the user or by the code?

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* some code here that must be run if the user edits the box, but not if the code edits the box */
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Text = "hello world";
    /* the TextBox_TextChanged function is fired */
}
```

Comment: Just one random suggestion: Use a (bool) flag that is being set by your code when it is going to alter the TextBox content. The TextChanged event handler would then check the state of the flag (and would also need to reset the flag again). There might be other ways of doing it, but it would entirely depend on the logic/control flow of your program...

Comment: Since that event fires *every single time a key is pressed* reconsider whether it is the ideal event for the job

Comment: I would say the most straight-forward way would be to use the [`Modified` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.modified) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412620/4934172).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I forgot about that Modified property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well following the comment of @elgonzo, you basically have to do that:

```
bool byCode;    

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(byCode == true)
    {
         //textbox was changed by the code...
    }
    else
    {
         //textbox was changed by the user...
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byCode = true; 
    textBox.Text = "hello world";
    byCode = false;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reset the _byCode_ flag in the event handler...

Answer (score 0):

```
bool automationLatch;
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    automationLatch = true;
    textBox.Text = "hello world";
    automationLatch = false;
    /* the TextBox_TextChanged function is fired */
}
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!automationLatch){
    /* some code here that must be run if the user edits the box, but not if the code edits the box */
    }
}
```