# Modified property of TextBox vs RichTextBox (is it a bug?)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

In WinForms, a [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and a [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) are both inheriting the [TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class, meaning that the [Modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.modified?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property should work the same. Yet, they don't.

How I found this? Let me explain the context.
I have to check the value of a TextBox when the `TextChanged` event fires (aka, when the user is typing something), and if I find the letter "A" for example, I have to call another function.
BUT, I also have to sometimes change the TextBox's text programmatically (aka, `myTxtBox.Text = "ABC";`), and (as you might have guessed) I DON'T want to call that other function when the text I set also contains the letter "A".

How to solve this? Two options in my opinion:

1. Use a bool like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672760/3153116).
2. Use the [Modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.modified?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property which I find to be the best option, so I am using it like so (in a `TextChanged` event):

`if (sender is not null && !((TextBox)sender).Modified) { return; }`

**But everything fails when I implement this on a RichTextBox**, which is weird for me since both should work the same when it comes to the Modified property.
**The `Modified` property is always set to `true` no matter if the text was changed by the user or by code.**

**My question is, did I just found a bug or am I stupid?**

Comment: You want to react to changes in the field only if it was done by the user, right?

Comment: The two .NET Controls inherit from the same class, but these are not the same System control at all. The Rich Edit Control handles a In / Out Stream that the Edit Control doesn't have. This sets the modified flag. The `Modified` property of a .NET Control is get / set, so set it yourself: `richTextBox1.Text = "Some text"; richTextBox1.Modified = false;`

Comment: @HopexDevelopment no, I want to know wheater the control's value/text was modified by the user or by the code.

Comment: @Jimi interesting, thanks for the info! This option is more or less the same as my first mentioned option (using a bool).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method, something like:

```
public static void SetText(this RichTextBox rtb, string text)
{
    rtb.Modified = true;
    rtb.Text = text;
    rtb.Modified = false;
}
```

Then use it in the combination with your TextBox solution:

```
if (sender is not null && !((TextBox)sender).Modified) { return; }
```